# Properly sort equal items in Collection

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, collections, comparator

According to [Documentation Java SE7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

> This sort is guaranteed to be *stable*: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

```
 Collections.sort(gpsDtoList, new Comparator<T>() {

                public int compare(T o1, T o2) {

                    return -o1.getEreigniszeit().compareTo(o2.getEreigniszeit());

                }
            });
```

Knowing this fact, how could I symbolize that these items are indeed equal, eventhough one is "higher" in the list (implicit meaning younger `timestamp`)

## Testdata

Let's say `o2.Ereigniszeit = 0000` and `o2.Ereigniszeit = 0000` *(This is just a very simple and abstract example)*

## The Crux

I later process this data and highlight the latest `(green)` and oldest `(red)` object on a Leaflet map with this logic

```
if (i == 0) {
   properties.put("markerStyle", LATEST);
   } else if (i == gpsDtoList.size() - 1) {
        properties.put("markerStyle", OLDEST);
   }
```

However they are literally `equal`, how should I properly handle it?
(I am processing alot of gps positions, so any `O(N^2)` would not be acceptable.)

The returning object is `GpsDTO`

```
public class GpsDTO implements Serializable {
    ....
    public Date getEreigniszeit() {
        return ereigniszeit;
    }

    public void setEreigniszeit(Date ereigniszeit) {
        this.ereigniszeit = ereigniszeit;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the class that `getEreigniszeit()` objects are returned?
By which properties you want to order this objects? Please give their names.

Comment: You are providing custom comparator anyway, why not check additional field in compare() in case getEreigniszeit() returns equal value?

Comment: @Yoda by `ereigniszeit`

Comment: @user158037 How could that help me? In the end one item is behind the first even though it's equal, no?

Comment: I would put them in `Map<GpsDTO, SortedSet<GpsDTO>>` so you have them grouped, then you can apply colors to them when rendering basing on their date or number of coordinates in the list, but I don't know how you want to indicate their age to the user(don't know your GUI), maybe if you would put them in a list, definetely not on the map as they're in the same place.

Comment: What is the problem that you have items with the same time exactly? It's not clear what the `properties.put("markerStyle")` is supposed to do and what it has to do with any object in the list.

Comment: @Yoda the youngest and oldest simply get a additional property, which causes a different Marker on the map.

Comment: @daniu it's a `JSONObject`, which will be parsed and the marker will receive this information

Comment: So you want to mark all objects with the lastest and newest time?

Comment: @daniu **IF** _N Objects_ are equal by date and happen to be the lastest or oldest marker, they should all have this property `markerstyle` (depending on their age, oldest or latest) put.

Comment: The way User's comment works is that they are never equal. You sort them based on a criteria, if that is equal then you issue the subsort criteria within that comparator. So to be equal they'd need to be equal on both criteria. It would necessarily result in them being in whatever order and sub-sorted order you want and you don't need to care if your sort is stable or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Solution

First I determine the latest and oldest dates.

```
Date youngestDate = null;
Date oldestDate = null;

Collections.sort(gpsDtoList, new Comparator<T>() {

            public int compare(T o1, T o2) {

                return -o1.getEreigniszeit().compareTo(o2.getEreigniszeit());

            }
        });

if (gpsDtoList != null && gpsDtoList.size() > 1) {
            youngestDate = gpsDtoList.get(0).getEreigniszeit();
            oldestDate = gpsDtoList.get(gpsDtoList.size() - 1).getEreigniszeit();
        }
```

and the actual setting logic

```
if (youngestDate != null && oldestDate != null) {
                if (i == 0 || youngestDate.equals(gpsDtoList.get(i).getEreigniszeit())) {
                    properties.put("markerStyle", LATEST);
                } else if (oldestDate.equals(gpsDtoList.get(i).getEreigniszeit())) {
                    properties.put("markerStyle", OLDEST);
                }

            }
```

## Testcases / Explanation

### #1 `o1,o2` are **equal**?

`youngestDate` and `oldestDate` will be set, however they are identical.

now, if `i=0` or equals `youngestDate` it is indeed `latest` and gains the property
else if equals `oldestDate` it is indeed oldest.

So we successfully set both `GpsDto` Objects to `latest`, since it will never run the `else if` Statement.

### #2 no data?

We made some null checks and we won't set special properties if there is no data.

### #3 just one `GpsDto` Object in the `List`?

We don't need to set any special properties here, for my definition it's "stateless" we do not know whether it's first or last. (Lazy me)

*If im not totally wrong I'm at O(n)*

Comment: It's just seems that you don't know what you want or you can't put it in words. I presume reason of this downvote is how much this answer corresponds to your question.

Comment: @Yoda what exactly was unclear? I thought after the discussion in the comments it was more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a `NavigableMap`; those are sorted by their key.

```
// entries will be sorted by your comparator
NavigableMap<Date, List<GpsDTO>> map = new TreeMap<yourComparator>();
// if there is a list already, it will be used; otherwise, a new one will be created
gpsDtoList.forEach(dto -> 
    map.computeIfAbsent(dto.getEreigniszeit(), new ArrayList<>())
                            .add(dto));

// iterate the relevant lists to set the respective markers
map.firstEntry().forEach(dto -> dto.setOldest());
if (map.size() > 1) {
    map.lastEntry().forEach(dto -> dto.setNeweset());
}
```

Here's the same without lambdas:

```
NavigableMap<Date, List<GpsDTO>> map = new TreeMap<yourComparator>();
for (GpsDTO dto : gpsDtoList) {
    List<GpsDTO> list = map.computeIfAbsent(dto.getEreigniszeit());
    list.add(dto);
}

for (GpsDTO firstDto : map.firstEntry()) {
    setOldestProperty(firstDto);
}
if (map.size() > 1) {
    for (GpsDTO lastDto : map.lastEntry()) {
        setNewestProperty(lastDto);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my solution is somehow similar to yours, however I haven't worked alot with NaviableMaps, that's why I'm a bit sceptical and I find it hard to read streams :O
But thanks for your effort!
PS: Do you think your solution is more performant?

Comment: @0x45 It should be O(n); one sweep through the list to collect the items into the map, then the iteration through the two sublists which adds n additional operations at most. I can add a non-lambda version.

Comment: It would be O(2*n) because you have to touch every item twice. O(n^n) would mean you have to iterate the full list once for every item in the list. Also, I added a safeguard against the newest and oldest date being the same.

Comment: @0x45 I've grown a bit rusty on complexity theory, but IIRC yes. Doubt you can do better; O(n) at least because you have to be sure to be able to collect every element.